# Vb.net combobox name issue

Tags: vb.net

I want to concat two strings and I need the name of a combo box to be the result of concatenation. For example,

```
parametre = hi

parametre2 = everyone
```

I have put name hieveryone my combobox name

```
parametre3 = String.Concat(parametre,parametre2)

dim parametre3 as ComboBox
```

How can I do solve this problem?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to refer to a ComboBox named "hieveryone", or do you want to select the option "hieveryone" inside the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim parameter1 As New String("Hi");
Dim parameter2 As New String("everyone");
Dim combo As New ComboBox();
combo.Name = String.Concat(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. Variable naming occurs at *compile* time, whereas the string concatenation occurs at *execution* time.

Generally, if you want to dynamically map strings to values, you should use a `Dictionary(Of String, Of ComboBox)` or whatever. Then you can put values into the dictionary by string key, and retrieve them later.